# Initializing arrays in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How do I initialize the array Save_state? This statement is giving X value at the output:

```
reg [9:0] count 
 reg [9:0] Save_state [0: 1024]; 

 always @ (posedge Clock )
 Count <=count+1 ;
 Save_state[count] <=count ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an initial block as well. This is allowed in simulation and is synthesizable on some architectures (Xilinx FPGA and CPLD support register initialization)

```
reg [9:0] count 
reg [9:0] Save_state [0: 1024]; 

integer i;
initial begin
  count = 0;
  for (i=0;i<=1024;i=i+1)
    Save_state[i] = 0;
end

always @ (posedge Clock ) begin
   count <= count + 1;
   Save_state[count] <= count;
end
```

Although for this particular example, in which the elements of the Save_state array will always have the same value, you can do like this (synthesizable on Xilinx and Altera, AFAIK):

```
reg [9:0] Save_state [0: 1024]; 

integer i;
initial begin
  for (i=0;i<=1024;i=i+1)
    Save_state[i] = i[9:0];
end
```

And at the beginning of you simulation, Save_state already have the values 0,1,2,...,1023 stored in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reset port to initialize `count` and `save_state` such as the following code :

```
integer i;
reg [9:0] count;
reg [9:0] save_state [0:1024];

always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) begin
        count <= 0;
        for (i=0; i<=1024; i=i+1)
            save_state[i] <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        count <= count + 1;
        save_state[count] <= count;
    end
end
```

The two statements inside the `else` block is applied at the same time and at the end of `always` block.

Comment: If you use non-blocking assigment both statements on the else block are applied at the same time

Comment: Yes, thanks. Both statements inside the `else` block is applied at the same time and at the end of `always` block.